# Extract fields and its path from json object using python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, indexing

I got json object from elasticsearch index mapping
I want to group index fields from json object based on its type.

https://gist.github.com/akthodu/47404880d2e5b6480a881214d41feb58

long field

```
act.sdeactLongDescription.properties.id.type
act.properties.actstate.type
```

text field:

```
act.properties.sdeactLongDescription.longDescription.type
```

I get string object when I loop through the output given from json.loads. Is there any json library to extract inner elements like bs4?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a recursive function and look for the end of the chain, like this:

```
import json

d = open('test.json')
test = json.load(d, strict=False)


# You could add the chain of keys to a list
def recursive_items(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            # Value becomes a sub-dictionary
            yield from recursive_items(value)
        else:
            # End of the chain
            yield (key, value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for key, value in recursive_items(test):
        print(key, value)

# Regex might work too (this pattern could prob be improved a lot)

import re
pattern = r'[^,]+"type"[^,]+'
matches = re.findall(pattern, string, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I am looking for whole tree. like. act.sdeactLongDescription.properties.id.type

Comment: Ah yeah, I tried expanding on that recursive thing, but it didn't go well. Regex with minified json looks promising though! This can probably be improved, but: r'[^,]+"long"[^,]+' seems to work okay. Cheers!